# Inline Javascript not working properly on rerendering a partial in ruby on rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my project we have inline javascript in a partial which is using some instance variables. When we are rerendering that partial after successful ajax call that script is not running.

Can you please help me that how I can solve that problem?

For e.g.

_partial.html.erb

```
 <div class="someclass"></div>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".someclass").hide();
    });
 </script>
```

The scrip tag is not running on replacing this partial from js.erb file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page has already been loaded. The `ready` event is passed long time ago, nobody is listening that now.

So, if you have `$(document).ready` in Ajax loaded script, the code will never be executed.

Solution:

Remove "ready" event and fire the code directly:

```
 <div class="someclass"></div>
 <script>
   $(".someclass").hide();
 </script>
```

Comment: thanx for the response, but its still not working. One more plugin we are using in the script is draggable, `$('.someclass').draggable();` it runs the first time but not after rerendering the partial. and I am using instance variable so i can't move this code into a common js file

Comment: @abhas, please check if the html is correctly delivered(not escapted html and js) if you use Rails to generate the code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that ready event is not triggered after manual update of DOM on ajax success event, so callback function is not been executed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer which I think were well suited for my requirement is to put the javascript into the `js.erb` partial and render it accordingly in `html.erb` and other `js.erb files`.